# Firebase online/offline snippet's first response always 'offline'

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

On initial load, when Angular app needs to check if Firebase online/offline to enable/disable certain features, how to prevent Firebase respond on first callback 'offline'

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBAE_URL);
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value',
  function(connectedSnap) {
     if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
       console.log("online");
     } else {
      console.log("offline");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.info/connected` child always responds with the current connection status. If you attach it early in the lifecycle of your application, the Firebase client is busy connecting to the servers, so it won't be connected yet.

There is no way to change this behavior, except for potentially attaching the listener later in the lifecycle.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. It would be nice if we can have a snippet for connection listener on initial load

Comment: It's unclear to me what that snippet would do. Would it wait til the value becomes `true` for the first time? That is easy to write (similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f)). But that would never fire if you're offline, which I think is not the behavior you're looking for. The next iteration would wait-for-true with some time-out. But what time-out value? What is reasonable in one region is unreasonably long/short in another. There may be a good answer for your specific app's needs, but there isn't a single answer that will work for all Firebase's users.